# Filter a list when text is change in a ListFragment

Tags: android, list, android-listfragment

I have a fragment which extends ListFragment. This fragment includes also an EditText element, and I want to filter the list when its text is changing.

I thought about the following code:

```
    EditText inputSearch = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.inputGroupSearch);
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            getListAdapter().getFilter().filter(cs);
        }});
```

But, somehow getListAdapter() doesn't has "getFilter()" method.
I would love to get a better idea to solve it out.

Thanks!

Comment: You can implement a custom fillter using filterable http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html

Comment: Can I implement a Filterable interface to the adapter of the default list on the ListFragment? can you show me how? or direct me to a suitable place?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, list.TERM));
   lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true); 
   et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
   {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
      // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,
    int start, int count, int after)
    {
    // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start, int before, int count)
    {
    textlength = et.getText().length();
    array_sort.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
    {
       if (textlength <= words[i].length())
       {
          if(et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String)words[i].subSequence(0, textlength)))
               {
                 array_sort.add(words[i]);
               }
       }
    }
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, array_sort));
  }
   });
```

Comment: Thanks! You help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47974521/filter-data-by-input-in-custom-arrayadapter-displays-empty-items/47974785#47974785

Answer (score 0):

Typecast the adapter returned by getListAdapter into your own custom adapter

```
filerText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.filerText);
filerText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {   
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        YourCustomAdapter adapter = (YourCustomAdapter)getListAdapter();
        adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) { }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {}
});
```